# Open and hide WPF application using NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have created an application in Microsoft Visual Studio. The application will mostly run in the background and I want the user to be able to open the application by clicking on the icon in the notification to open the window to see the progress and interact with the process. I have found a [tutorial about how to add a NotifyIcon to WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon) This tutorial appears to be using this; [Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf/)

I have been able to show the Notify Icon but I am having problems to keep the NotifyIcon open when I close my application. Once I close the MainWindow the Debug process finishes. I am stuck on this part in this tutorial;

```
public class App
{
  private TaskbarIcon tb;

  private void InitApplication()
  {
    //initialize NotifyIcon
    tb = (TaskbarIcon) FindResource("MyNotifyIcon");
  }
}
```

My application `App.xaml.cs`

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
}
```

I don't see how I can add `TaskbarIcon ScraperNotifyIcon = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("ScraperNotifyIcon");` Since this is a function of the `MainWindow` and it has not been loaded at this point. In what method do I put it in?

I have a `ResourceDictionary` where I have added the NotifyIcon which looks like this ;

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar">
    <!-- Globally declared notify icon -->
    <tb:TaskbarIcon IconSource="/AttorneyScraper;component/images/magnifying-glass/magnifying_glass512_Q32_icon.ico" ToolTipText="Attorney Scraper" x:Key="AttorneyScraperNotifyIcon" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The icon shows fine when I add it to the class `MainWindow` which I think is WPF. But I want to load the NotifyIcon independent of the `MainWindow` and open or close the MainWindow when clicked. It looks like the tutorial was following me on that pass but I got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I think what the tutorial is missing is [Application.ShutdownMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx). By default WPF app closes when its last window is closed ([OnLastWindowClose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx)).

You can try changing the ShutdownMode to OnExplicitShutdown:

> An application shuts down only when Shutdown is called.

You can change the ShutdownMode like this:

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
</Application>
```

Regarding [FindResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource(v=vs.110).aspx), you can access it outside your MainWindow like this:

`Application.Current.FindResource("MyNotifyIcon");`

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the sample application, which is bundled with the CodeProject tutorial? It contains various samples, including a windowless one that shows how to open / close an app window from the tray.